# Google App Engine Spring Security login failure issue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-security

I am using Spring Security module in google app engine.

If i do a successful login(with correct credentials), then it redirects successfully to the home page.

If the login fails once with bad credentials, then the second attempt even with correct credentials will not redirect me to home page, it stays in the error login page.

Piece of Security-Context.xml

```
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page='/login.jsp' authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=1"  default-target-url="/"/>
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login.jsp" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
      <user-service>
        <user name="guest1" password="guest1" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        <user name="guest2" password="guest2" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
      </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Please let me know if you need more details. You can test this problem at http://relation-ship.appspot.com/

The 2 credentials for accessing http://relation-ship.appspot.com/ is guest1,guest1 and guest2,guest

Thanks,
Ramesh.V

Comment: can you enable DEBUG logging and see what Spring has to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is due to spring version 3.0.6.RELEASE, i changed to 3.0.5.RELEASE solved my problem.

Thanks